# Spark only uses 1CPU when 2x4CPU are available on reduce()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-1.6

I have 3 machines: 1x Master with 4x CPU, 8G RAM ; 2x executors with 4x CPU and 16G RAM.

The master is **standalone mode** (no YARN), I'm using pyspark.

Even if it is not a huge infrastructure I would still expect some perf out of it.
When running a `reduce` operation:

```
tfsent = tfsent.reduce(lambda x,y: Row(tf=spvecadd(x.tf, y.tf), sentiment=spvecadd(x.sentiment, y.sentiment)))
```

where `tfsent` has `tf` and `sentiment` which are `SparseVector`, and `spvecadd` is an home made function to add `SparseVector`

Doing this, on the 3x 4CPU, only one, on an executor, is running 100%. Others are 0%, memory is around 5G/16G. 
I don't get:
* Why is this so long
* Why is only 1x CPU working.

Should I partition my data myself? (I mean explicitely distribute the data on both executors? even if to my mind thats Spark's job).

Thanks for any help, ideas or tips
pltrdy

## Additional Informations

- Both executors are connected to the master and "assigned" to the task (can check it using spark web UI)
- I have around 380k line. Both Vector dimension is less than 100. 
  (which is not a lot).
- Complexity may be way more dependent of the dimension than the number of rows.

## Update

It turns out that I have to use `repartition(8)` to make the RDD distributed. This solved my problem but not entirely my question: why do I have to do this?

I guess that it is because of how I get the data. I'm reading from database i.e.

```
df = (sqlContext
        .read.format('jdbc')
        .options(url=c.url, dbtable='(%s) tmp '%initial_query, user=c.user, password=c.password)
        .load())
```

which, i guess store without distributing it.

Comment: Do you use Yarn mode ? please provide more infos about the configuration.

Comment: Nope, its standalone. post edited, which info would you need?

Comment: How do you submit your job?